# How to give a container a shinny glassmorphism look in flutter, with shinny borders?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to code a glassmorphism container that looks like a shiny glass with shining border.

Comment: You can use BackdropFilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the flutter BackdropFilter Widget and properties, and try to have this over the colored spots.

`BackdropFilter` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html

also, use the Glassmorphism package to achieve a similar effect.

`Glassmorphism` https://pub.dev/documentation/glassmorphism

Comment: Yes, this does help a lot in creating a glassmorphistic look but I need shinny borders. I am using a backdrop filter for the glassmorphism look.

Comment: @VarunLohade Kindly provide an example.